# Filling without boundaries

Tags: plotting, graphics, filling

How to fill the area between two curves, but without plotting those curves?

For example,

`Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Filling -> {1 -> 0.5}]`

gives a plot like this

[image]

(0.5 without any marked boundary =  form required for a generalization)

but   `Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Filling -> {1 -> (Sin[x] - 0.5)}]`

draws a plot without filling or even gives an error

Comment: `PlotStyle -> None`?

Comment: wow, thank you @Kuba

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to using `PlotStyle->None` as suggested by @Kuba, you can also do:

**Post-process to remove the `Line` primitives:**

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Filling -> {1 -> 0.5}] /. _Line :> Sequence[]
```

[image]

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Sin[x] - 0.5}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}}] /. _Line :> Sequence[]
```

[image]

**Use `ParametricPlot` with options `BoundaryStyle -> None` and `Mesh -> None`:**

```
ParametricPlot[{x, t Sin[x] + (1 - t) .5}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {t, 0, 1}, 
 BoundaryStyle -> None, Mesh -> None, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, Frame -> False]
```

[image]

```
ParametricPlot[{x, t Sin[x] + (1 - t) (Sin[x] - 0.5)}, {x, 0, 2 Pi}, {t, 0, 1}, 
 BoundaryStyle -> None, Mesh -> None, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, Frame -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Would there is a reason for `RuleDelayed` here `/. _Line :> Sequence[]`  instead of just `Rule`?

Comment: @hana, no reason (just habitual use of  `:>` when there is a pattern on the LHS)